# Matlab external editor on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, editor

I'm currently switching to linux from windows, and I'd like to use matlab in `-nodesktop` mode. I configured gedit to open .m files with Matlab syntax highlighting, and that is ok. But I'm not able to start gedit (or any other external editor) via the `edit` command.

How should I configure the external editor in Matlab preferences? I tried selecting `Text Editor` and setting it to `/usr/bin/gedit` (or `/usr/bin/emacs`), but It's not working.

I'm running Matlab r2016b under Ubuntu 16.10

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

When running MATLAB in the console, the `edit` command respects the `EDITOR` environment variable. To set that, simply call

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/gedit
```

in the terminal, before you run `matlab`. If you always work with  gedit, you can add that line to your `.bashrc` file, which is automatically loaded when opening a terminal window.